Deducting Values from one DataFrame based on Values from another Table (With common Columns)
I have a simple case where I have two tables, one represents demand and another is supplies. I want to pick up an order, if the order is from the same location and Item as supplies then substract the supply with the order. The remaining supply is used for the subsequent orders.


Currently, I'm doing this by doing a .apply() function in pandas along with .groupby() on the demand table, where I find each order and then find the relevant supply for that order based on Item Location. Do the substraction and calculation and then update the supply table.
I tried merging and then trying cumulativesum, but cumsum() just sums up for every row (which has multiple Item Location combinations) which is useless.
I try grouping the orders by Item Location, and then do cumsum and index to find the order where the demand exceeds supply, but then the problem is that I have to respect the priority while fulfilling orders which can be for multiple Item Locations.
My main issue is with the apply() function where I'm going over every order and then finding the supply that's available, and then subtracting the supply that will be used for order. Syntax is below in python
def match_demand_Supply(demands,supply):
    demands = demands.sort_values(by=["Priority"],ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    def match_by_order(one_order):
        Item,Location = one_order["Item"].iloc[0], one_order["Location"].iloc[0]
        one_order = one_order.merge(supply, on = ["Item","Location"],how = 'left')
        one_order["Fulfilled Quantity"] = one_order["Demand Quantity"] if one_order["Supply"] > = one_order["Demand Quantity"] else one_order["Supply"]
        Remaining_supply = max(0,one_order["Supply"].iloc[0] - one_order["Demand Quantity"].iloc[0])
        supply.loc[supply["Item"]== Item & supply["Location"]== Location, Supply] = Remaining_supply
        return one_order
    fulfilled_orders = demands.apply(match_by_order)
    return fulfilled_orders

Main question is how do I vectorize this so that it is more efficient for lot of orders (in terms of 10^4)
Thanks

1- please provide your current apply code, 2- please provide the inputs as code (images are not acceptable) and provide the matching expected output

@mozway I've added the code and a bit more explanation.

Your code is not functional, please make sure it is, provide the inputs  and how you run it (as code), and provide the matching expected output.

While the question is unclear, if your goal is just to update the Supply table to get the used/remaining supply, you could just groupby.sum, merge and sub with clip.
Assuming df_demand/df_supply the inputs:
tmp = (df_demand.groupby(['Item', 'Location'])['Demand Quantity'].sum()
       .reset_index(name='Supplies')
       .merge(df_supplies[['Item', 'Location']], how='right')
       .set_axis(df_supplies.index)
      )

df_supplies['Remaining'] = (df_supplies['Supplies'].sub(tmp['Supplies'])
                            .clip(lower=0)
                            )
df_supplies['Used'] = df_supplies['Supplies'].sub(df_supplies['Remaining'])

Output:
  Item Location  Supplies  Remaining  Used
0   I1       L1       500        250   250
1   I2       L1       500        350   150
2   I3       L2       500        300   200
3   I4       L1       500        250   250

